# Unity cheap fluids visuals for VR using Post Processing

Tags: unity, shaders, virtual-reality, post-processing

I'm trying to create a turret in VR that will spray water onto a wall. I need a way that will take the collision of the fluid and transfer that to a splatmap to change the material of the wall. I know how to do that. What I need from this community is a way to make the liquid coming out of the turret looks semi realistic. The game is based in a simulation so it doesn't need to look completely realistic, but I don't want it to look out of place.

I've done some research into this and found [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FR618z5xEiM) and they talk about using spheres then isolating the layer and applying some post processing to it. And it's that last part that I'm struggling with. I'm coming from UE4 and have some decent understanding of how post processing works in that engine but not in Unity. The video I found doesn't go into the code in depth and I'm currently downloading it to look over, but if there is anyone on here that can at least point me in the right direction, I'd appreciate it. In the meantime, I'll see if I can get this to work.

Comment: Did you check the related links in the video description? They go into more detail, including some resources I was about to recommend in a comment before noticing that the video already mentioned them.

Comment: @DMGregory Well, I feel like a right idiot now xD. I'm checking them out now